# Hide IonMenu from login and registrationpage

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-react

there I'm building an app with Ionic and react and firebase as a backend. I'm trying to hide the side menu (IonMenu) from the login and registration page.

I'm kind of new to programming so I'm kind of lost. Can someone put me in the right direction?

Here is my App.tsx file

```
    <IonApp>
      <IonReactRouter>
        <IonSplitPane contentId="main">
          <Menu />
          <IonRouterOutlet id="main">
            <Route exact path="/home" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/galeria" exact component={Galeria}  />
            <Route path="/liturgia" exact component={Liturgia} />
            <Route path="/trabajos" exact component={Trabajos}  />
            <Route path="/pagos" exact component={Pagos} />
            <Route path="/login" exact component={Login} />
            <Route path="/register" exact component={Register} /> 
            <Redirect exact from="/" to="/login" />

          </IonRouterOutlet>
        </IonSplitPane>

      </IonReactRouter>
    </IonApp>

);

export default App;
```

Comment: Can't guide you on React but there is a `disabled` prop that seems to accomplish what you want: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/menu#properties

Comment: I have seen that property but I was not able to apply it for some reason... Thank do